# referring to last value of a column as default in a form in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to build a time in motion tracker with Access 2010 at work and populate a respective table (named `rawDataTimeInMotion`) with the following column names: "from" (format date and time), "to" (format date and time), "category" (format text), "location" (format text) and "comments" (format memo). The reason I'm using Access (rather than an online tool as toggl.com) is to allow the recording of potentially confidential information.

To streamline data entry, I created a form with a text box for each column above. I would like to refer in the "from" text box (bound to the "from" column above) to the latest entry in the "to" column as a default value.

I tried playing around at Form Design Tools --> Design --> Property Sheet --> Data --> Default Value to add a default for the "from" textbox (for instance by choosing the minimum or maximum value of the "to" column as default with `=Min([rawDataTimeInMotion]![to])` or `=Max([rawDataTimeInMotion]![to])`, respectively), however this only returned "30/12/1899 00:00" (which doesn't make sense to me) when adding a new record.

I also googled around and attempted guidance in https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/setting-the-default-value-to-the-last-used-value.279442/ without success (the default value remained empty for new records).

Is there a solution for this without the use of Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of the form to set the DefaultValue property as a *text expression* of the date value:

```
Me![From].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Me![To].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I entered `rawDataTimeInMotion![from].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(rawDataTimeInMotion![to].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"` at Form Design Tools --> Design --> Property Sheet --> Event --> After Update. The "from" remained empty when going to a New (blank) record in the Layout view. I also entered the line above to Form Design Tools --> Design --> Property Sheet --> Event --> Before Update with the same effect. Adding `=[rawDataTimeInMotion]![to].[Value]` to Property Sheet --> Data --> Default Value only returned "#Name?".

Comment: rawDataTimeInMotion is the table containing the time in motion data

Comment: 1) Use the code I posted and explained. 2) A default value will not be set until you have created or modified a record.

Comment: I copied and pasted `Me![From].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Me![To].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"` to the After Update Event as above. There are plenty of records in the underlying table, unfortunately the "from" textbox in the Layout view remains empty. Changing capital letters of the column names as per `Me![from].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Me![to].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"` didn't help, either.

Comment: Have in mind, please, that it will only show up on a _new_ record.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that it only applies to a new record (I tried to indicate this by referring to a "New (blank) record" above). The "from" textbox remains empty in the Form View as in the Layout View. I understand I cannot post a screenshot here.

Comment: Can't tell. It is tested and runs here, so double-check.

Comment: I re-created the database from scratch with one table (with example data) and one form. Unfortunately the code above still doesn't work. The database can be downloaded from https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai-ZtzXXReuhsno78-yXpRFXW7Cc?e=hJi6bO.

Comment: You have to insert the code in the form's code module. I did that, and it worked right away.

Comment: Have you downloaded the sample database from the link above?- I was only referring to items in Form Design Tools --> Design --> Property Sheet so far. I'm not sure what the "form's code module" is. Are you referring to Form Design Tools --> Design --> View Code? This opens a Visual Basic window (which I hoped we could avoid). There, the "AfterUpdate" property includes the code above. The behaviour of the form is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, I selected the _AfterUpdate_ event, opened the _VBEditor_, copy-pasted the code line into the Sub, compiled and saved the code and form, and it ran as intended.

Comment: I went to Form Design Tools --> Design --> View Code and in the appearing window found a smaller window where I selected from the top "from" and "AfterUpdate". I then added the following code:  `Private Sub from_AfterUpdate()` `Me![from].DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Me![to].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"` `End Sub` (in consecutive lines). Result: Nothing.

Comment: If you enter a `to` date on an existing record, that date will be the default `from` date when you go to a new record.

Comment: Except it doesn't work. - I think I'll have to think about alternative solutions.

Comment: Can't tell what you are missing. This is so simple - one code line - and is tested and works here.